# WPF edit autogenerated column header text

Tags: wpf, datagridview

I'm using a WPF `DataGrid` to display `DataTable`'s.
I need to be able to edit this bound DataTables (Two-Way Binding).

I'm using the DataGrid as followed:

```
<DataGrid SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.BindableContent, FallbackValue={x:Null}}" />
```

The Problem I have, the user can't edit the `ColumnHeader`'s like cell content or rows.
The Screenshot below illustrates that porblem. The only thing I can do is sort the columns.
Is there a way to edit the column headers too, for example when the user clicks twice, or presses <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Maybe some `Style`' or a `HeaderTemplate` will do the job? I have already tried some styles and control templates I've found around the internet, but without any success.

[image: Editable Cells, but not editable Col Headers]

#### EDIT:

I managed to display the column headers in a `TextBox` (and not in a `TextBlock`) within the AutogeneratingTextcolumn event handler:

[image: Column Header Text in TextBox]

```
private void _editor_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) {
  // First: create and add the data template to the parent control
  DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextBox));
  e.Column.HeaderTemplate = dt;

  // Second: create and add the text box to the data template
  FrameworkElementFactory txtElement =
      new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
  dt.VisualTree = txtElement;

  // Create binding
  Binding bind = new Binding();
  bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
  bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

  // Third: set the binding in the text box
  txtElement.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
  txtElement.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, e.Column.Header);
}
```

But I couldn't manage to set the binding correctly, if i edit the Text in the TextBoxes, it does not change the text in the `Column.Header`-Property (which is auto-generated by a binding to a `DataTable` like explained above).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the source of your binding and you mustn't set the value after the registration of the binding. The correct code would be the following:

```
private void asdf_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextBox));
        e.Column.HeaderTemplate = dt;

        FrameworkElementFactory txtElement =
            new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        dt.VisualTree = txtElement;

        Binding bind = new Binding();
        bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Header");
        bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        // set source here
        bind.Source = e.Column;

        txtElement.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
        // You mustn't set the value here, otherwise the binding doesn't work
        // txtElement.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, e.Column.Header);
    }
```

Additionally you must change the binding property to `Header`, because you are adding the binding to the text property of the TextBox.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution, but the behaivior of the bounded text is thill the same, the `DataGrid` displays the text now, but when I edit the text in the textbox it is not updating the text in the `DataTable` (the DataContext of the GridView).